# How to colorize terminal output on Mac Catalina

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a new **Mac** with `Catalina` I am trying to get the same colorized terminal output as on my other mac and I am using the same `.bash` script but I am getting the following output:

```
\[\]\u \[\]at \[\]\h \[\]in \[\]\w\[\]$([[ -n $(git branch 2> /dev/null) ]] && echo " on ")\[\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\]\n$ \[\]
```

Here is the script I am using:

```
if [[ $COLORTERM = gnome-* && $TERM = xterm ]]  && infocmp gnome-256color >/dev/null 2>&1; then export TERM=gnome-256color
elif [[ $TERM != dumb ]] && infocmp xterm-256color >/dev/null 2>&1; then export TERM=xterm-256color
fi

if tput setaf 1 &> /dev/null; then
    tput sgr0
    if [[ $(tput colors) -ge 256 ]] 2>/dev/null; then
      MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 9)
      ORANGE=$(tput setaf 172)
      GREEN=$(tput setaf 190)
      PURPLE=$(tput setaf 141)
      WHITE=$(tput setaf 0)
    else
      MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
      ORANGE=$(tput setaf 4)
      GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
      PURPLE=$(tput setaf 1)
      WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
    fi
    BOLD=$(tput bold)
    RESET=$(tput sgr0)
else
    MAGENTA="\033[1;31m"
    ORANGE="\033[1;33m"
    GREEN="\033[1;32m"
    PURPLE="\033[1;35m"
    WHITE="\033[1;37m"
    BOLD=""
    RESET="\033[m"
fi

parse_git_dirty () {
  [[ $(git status 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" ]] && echo "*"
}
parse_git_branch () {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/\1$(parse_git_dirty)/"
}
PS1="\[${BOLD}${MAGENTA}\]\u \[$WHITE\]at \[$ORANGE\]\h \[$WHITE\]in \[$GREEN\]\w\[$WHITE\]\$([[ -n \$(git branch 2> /dev/null) ]] && echo \" on \")\[$PURPLE\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$WHITE\]\n\$ \[$RESET\]"
```

What has changed? I put this in my `.bash_profile`

Comment: Output the result of `echo $SHELL`. Mac Catalina defaults to zsh as the shell.

Answer (score 4):

So thanks to those on Stack Overflow my default shell is `zsh` so I had to run

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

And that fixed the problem.